# How to Setup Multiple Authentication Types for 1 Subversion Repo?

Tags: apache, authentication, sspi

We have an SVN 1.4 repository that uses Apache 2.0 for authentication; specifically, the `mod-auth-sspi` module to authenticate with our Windows Domain.  The relevant portion of `httpd.conf` looks like this:

```
<Location /svn>
    AuthType SSPI
    AuthName "My Subversion"
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIDomain MYDOMAIN
    SSPIFixDomainCase On
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    Require group MYDOMAIN\MYDOMAINGROUP
</Location>
```

We also have an automated build server which needs to get the source from SVN and build it.  Naturally, this requires that the build server pass valid Domain credentials to SVN/Apache.

Today, we do this by using my own Domain credentials.  This is not such a good idea, since something bad could happen to me or I could be on vacation when my Domain password expires -- the whole auto build process would freeze.  Creating a special account on the Domain just for the auto build server is not an option at this time because I work for a huge company and the red tape to do such a thing is prohibitive.

What I'd like to do is leave the existing SSPI authentication scheme the same, but create a local account on the machine hosting SVN and have the auto build server authenticate using that local account.  In other words, two different authentication paths (SSPI + a local account) for the one SVN repository.

Is that possible?  How do I do it?

Comment: Also just an Apache question. The fact that the <Location> is an SVN repo doesn't matter.

Comment: unfortunately this is not programming topic, but configuration for commonly available software. serverfault better suits.

Comment: this is resolved elsewhere. use deny,allow, next deny from all, allow from specified build host and last one require any. examples are on stack and serverfault . find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide basic authentication in addition to SSPI authentication, you need to provide it under a different URL, e.g.

```
  <Location /svn_pass>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "svn"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svnusers
    require valid-user
  </Location>
```

Alternatively, you can use host-based authorization, which you can then also put into the current URL, and specify "Satisfy Any".

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is instead of multiple authentication methods, leave what you already have working in place, and setup svnserve so that your build server has its own credentials.

Subversion will happily work using [multiple repository access methods](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html).

Comment: there no info what OS is using. is there available ssh+svn ? maybe the simplest way is creating another URL for special automated access without prompted authentication.